# Asp.Net C# SQL Server (local) Multi-user application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a novice so I apologize in advance for lack of information provided or not asking my question in exactly the right way. I've been searching far and wide and have found no resolution to the issue I am facing. I am trying to improve on a web application that was previously written by someone else utilizing asp.net c#. The web application accesses a SQL Server database (local). As each user is logged into the application a unique session ID is created. Everything seems to run smoothly until 2 users click on the same request at the same time. The application will freeze momentarily, eventually refresh but with severe effect on response time in the application. I've searched locking, threads, pagesections.....can't seem to find what I am after.

Comment: Could you be experiencing the [`ASP.NET Session exclusiveness`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149120/why-is-my-asp-net-site-acting-single-threaded) in which 2 parallel requests from the same user (`SessionID`) are executed sequentially due to the concurrency limitations of an ASP.NET session?