# IIS/DMZ - Site Slow

Tags: performance, web, iis, dmz

We have a DMZ setup that our web requests come in on.  This website has pages that take around 15-20 seconds to load and when website traffic rises the site comes to a crawl.

From my reading so far it looks like the problem is all the requests coming to the website from the DMZ use the same ip address and since IIS process's each request from the same ip sequentially the site slows down.  Does this sound accurate?

What would be a solution?

Comment: "since IIS process's each request from the same ip sequentially the site slows down" That's completely misunderstanding as IIS is multi-threading. Do some debugging please https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/919792/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-a-process-that-h

Comment: That is what I thought but, I have read on stackoverflow when you have debugging on it becomes single threaded and I'm wondering if any other settings in IIS can cause the same situation.

Comment: You read too much irrelevant things and I wonder from where you learned "when you have debugging on it becomes single threaded". Focus on the exact issue you hit and debug it in the right way. SO is full of good and bad threads, so unless you selectively read the proper ones, misunderstanding accumulates easily.

Comment: Here is where I read it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587420/iis7-only-serves-up-one-page-at-a-time-its-a-making-me-crazy

Comment: That thread only applies to classic ASP when server side script debugging is enabled, while any other scenarios won't fall into the same scope.