# IIS only processing one request at a time

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

We have an asp.net web application that works fine in our environment.  One of our partners tries to the exact same code in their environment and can only process one request at a time.  For example, there is only page that calls a long running stored procedure (5 minutes).  If you call that page and the try to open a new page, the new page won't serve until after the first page has completed.  We can see the request back up by looking at the worker processes for their application pool.   They are running IIS 8.5 on a windows 2012 server.  They're also running SQL Server 2016.

The database connection is structured the same as as in our environment.  The stored procedure is not wrapped in a transaction.  Any ideas what might be causing this behavior?

Comment: If you are using sessions, session access is serialized on a per-user-basis. Solution: Do not use session or do not use long running requests.

Comment: Some years back, I summed this up in a (German only, sorry) developer [forum post](https://entwicklergate.de/t/session-zugriffe-in-asp-net-sind-langsam/219?u=uwekeim). Maybe the links from there help you understanding the possible issue and find alternatives. (You may use the Google Chrome built-in translation feature to translate the forum posting to English).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIS also can work in the Debug mode, when it is enabled, Asp is limited to processing one request at a time in a single-threaded manner.
Open “InetMgr” or IIS manager, double click ASP under the IIS section of the website. Check the below settings in `Asp` section.
[image]
See the below discussion for more information.
[IIS7 - only serves up one page at a time. It's a making me crAzY!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587420/iis7-only-serves-up-one-page-at-a-time-its-a-making-me-crazy)